# Vertical align <p> "beside" <div>

Tags: html, css

Look the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7qm6husL/

I have set the `line-height` and `height` to `<p>`, everything has a same height, whether `<div>` or `<p>` act as a `inline-block`, I wonder why they are not align on the same horizontal line, and how can I fix it without `table-cell`.

Thanks.

---

All the codes:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box red"></div><p>Something</p>
    <div class="box yellow"></div><p>hello</p>
    <div class="box blue"></div><p>world</p>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 40px;
}
.wrapper p {
    background: #EEE;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
}

.red{background-color:#FFC2C2;}
.yellow{background-color:#FFB;}
.blue{background-color:#CEF0F5;}
```

Comment: Always post your relevant code in the question...

Comment: Define your .wrapper p, .box{margin:0;vertical-align:top;}  Demo link is this http://jsfiddle.net/7qm6husL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.wrapper p {
    margin:0;
}
.box{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Also, as you have given `inline-block` to div, make sure you comment out spaces.

[**See updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qm6husL/2/)

Comment: Why whether add `vertical-align: top` to `p` or `.box` can work?

Comment: because default value is  `baseline` for `<p>` element. thats why you need to set a `top` value in your case. so put ` vertical-align:top;` for `p`.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you are using any `inline` attribute, (*`p` in this case*), you *have*  to define its `alignment` which is not `top` by default.
So, in this case, while amending `p` to `inline-block`, you will need to declare the `vertical-align` also.

Make following changes to your **css**

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qm6husL/3/)**

```
.wrapper p {
    background: #EEE;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90px;
    line-height: 40px;
     margin:0;/**Add this**/
    vertical-align:top;/**Add this**/
}
```

Comment: `<p>` tag is block level element. check link.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Answer (score 1):

please try this Style :

```
.wrapper {
    height: 40px;
}
.wrapper p {
    background: #EEE;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90px;
    line-height: 40px;

    margin:0;
    margin-left:5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.red{background-color:#FFC2C2;}
.yellow{background-color:#FFB;}
.blue{background-color:#CEF0F5;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` has margin and/or padding by default so you are facing the problem with `p`.

```
.wrapper p {
    background: #EEE;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90px;
    margin: 0; /* this fixes the key problem you were facing */
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;

}
```

[here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qm6husL/4/)